# Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-api

I got the **SHA 1 certificate** from the **debug keystore**.

Using that I generated the **Google Map V2 Api key**.

I extended Fragment Activity.

I used "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" in my xml.

When I run this , it shows the following errors.
"Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers"
Authorization failed.

Can anybody help me to recover from this issue.

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
       package="com.example.demomap" 
       android:versionCode="1" 
       android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <permission
         android:name="com.example.demomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.demomap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDze1i1aL3O2H60NN1URt5g3tz5PA-JYUc"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_below="@id/header"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java code:

```
    package com.example.demomap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code??

Comment: when you got the key you put in the right sha1 key and the right package name seperated with a semicolon?

Comment: it could take a couple minutes to propagate the servers if you just got the key and ran it instantly

Comment: in services make sure you turned on the switch for Google Map Android  API v2 not Google Map V2 alot of people get that mixed up

Comment: @subburaj Hi I attached my xml, java, manifest code. Please inform what is wrong in it.

Comment: Try placing the `<meta-data>` element (API key) just before the closing tag `</application>`.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Api Console you need to go to services tab and ON Google Map Android API v2 . have you done it ?

Answer (score 0):

Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers issue with android google maps api v2
if you are getting this message with release api key - it means it is in debug mode. So export your app from eclipse and install the app.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Google Play Console is probably signing your uploaded app with its own certificate and creating another SHA1 fingerprint different to the one you use for enable your API Map. Use the one that you can find in your Google Play Console>Release Management>App Signing setting up that one in your Google Developer Console[image]